# Flow type array undefined

Tags: types, flowtype

I'm having trouble performing operations on an array item using .split() because FLOW thinks it COULD be undefined.

```
export const getTokenFromCookieRes = (cookies: string[]): mixed => {

  if (!cookies) {
    return undefined
  }

  if (0 in cookies) {
    return cookies[0] // cookies[0] returns an error for possibly being undefined
      .split(';')
      .find(c => c.trim().startsWith('jwt='))
      .split('=')[1]
  } else {
    return undefined
  }
}
```

[tryflow](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wObBgFQga2GQDEoIBbAYQgIEtgAlYVOAXjgAok7mAuOdFFrIMAbQC6ASn7laIYABM2APjgBvAFAa4cWgDNOAQm756qSeu064UbAFcoyOHeQLge4YqsBfLTv2cAAy6TiZmFprWNvaOiDSmzKKB4nAA9KlxPKhJKbYwDmhwAIZOwFBkUHB60HCQqKi0AEYANgCecI3AwhjOru6eClZRAHSoYM20MBwA5ADc05JD1sMerlwqiMMwQuQckqMwRbCoAOqTABYzAFYA7jCsC4tROqPjkzMPkqIAjOI+cMBmqhgJYonkCr03KsvDpfL4gA)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not that `cookies[0]` might be `undefined`; it's that the result of `find()` could be `undefined`.  You need to check the results of `find()` before trying to call `split()` on the string.

```
const getTokenFromCookieRes = (cookies?: string[]): mixed => {

  if (!cookies) {
    return undefined
  }

  if (!!cookies[0]) {
    const jwt = cookies[0] // No issues here
      .split(';')
      .find(c => c.trim().startsWith('jwt='))
      return jwt && jwt.split('=')[1];
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you - had to put them in separate functions to return values - but it worked!